A local variable seemingly breaking scope in Django
I have introduced this function in a file storage.py that is imported from models.py:
def uuid_file_name(kind):
    def file_name(instance, filename):
        h = str(uuid.uuid4())
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        return os.path.join(f'{kind}_files', h[0:1], h[1:2], h + ext.lower())
    return file_name

The intention of the function is to dynamically generate file names in a field declaration, such as:
class Thingy(models.Model):
    widget = FileField(upload_to=uuid_file_name("widget"))

Now when I makemigrations, I get an odd error:
ValueError: Could not find function file_name in <app>.storage.

There is no other mention of file_name in my project, and if I change the identifier, the error message changes accordingly, so the error is definitely from this. However, without some metaprogramming, I can't see how file_name can leak from within this function.
I thought I could avoid whatever magic was happening by from .storage import uuid_file_name as _uuid_file_name, hoping Django wouldn't act on a private module member, but the same error occurs.
So, a two-fold question:

Why is this happening, and how do I prevent it?

Is there another way to write the equivalent code to circumvent the error?



Full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<project>/./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "<project>/./manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 107, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 259, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 364, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 141, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 99, in serialize
    _write(arg_name, arg_value)
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 51, in _write
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(item)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 287, in serialize
    return serializer_factory(value).serialize()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 42, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = serializer_factory(item).serialize()
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 231, in serialize
    return self.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 96, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = serializer_factory(arg).serialize()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<project>/<venv>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 187, in serialize
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not find function file_name in <app>.storage.


Django must be able to serialize the values, which it can't do if it's a dynamically declared function in a nested scope. See the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing. It essentially falls into the category "lambdas" there.

A simple solution would be to assign uuid_file_name("widget") to a variable like widget_file_name = uuid_file_name("widget") and then use it like upload_to=widget_file_name

@deceze Thank you, changing from a wrapper to partial worked.
